Why Can't CKKS Encryption Be Inverted by Subtracting the Public Key from the Ciphertext?
In the CKKS scheme, encryption produces ciphertexts of the form $ct = v \cdot pk + (m + e_0, e_1)$, where $v \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$, $pk = (-as + e, a)$, and $m$ is the plaintext. Some blogs even simplify this to $ct = pk + (\mu, 0)$, ignoring the randomness $v$.
Given this structure, why can't an attacker who knows the ciphertext $ct$ and the public key $pk$ simply compute $ct - pk$ to extract something close to the plaintext $m$? It seems that $ct - pk$ would produce $(m + e_0, e_1)$ or $(\mu,0)$, but I know this must not work in practice.
Can someone explain clearly why this subtraction does not lead to an effective decryption? Is it due to the noise terms $e_0, e_1$, or some deeper security feature of CKKS?

$v$ is not an integer in $\{-1, 0, 1\}$, but a polynomial of degree bounded by $N$ and each coefficient in $\{-1, 0, 1\}$, thus, there are $3^N$ possible values of $v$.
